# Trying to convert each to while loop, creates TypeError. Why is it having a problem with symbols?

Tags: ruby, hash, typeerror, symbols

I have a finished program, but now I need to convert an #Each loop to a #While loop. The loop should output almost the same information, but it throws me a 'directory.rb:24:in `print': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)' instead.

```
def input_students
  puts "Please enter the names of the students"
  puts "To finish, just hit return twice"
  students = []
  name = gets.chomp
  while !name.empty? do
    students << {name: name, cohort: :november}
    puts "Now we have #{students.count} students"
    name = gets.chomp
  end
  students
end

students = input_students

def print_header
  puts "The students of Villains Academy"
  puts "----------"
end

def print(students)
  students.each.with_index(1) do |students, index|
    puts "#{index} #{students[:name]}, #{students[:cohort]} cohort"
  end
end

def print_footer(names)
  puts "Overall we have #{names.count} great students"
end


print_header
print(students)
print_footer(students)
```

Works as expected. I'm trying:

```
def print(students)
  i = 0
  while i < students.length
    puts "#{students[:name]}, #{students[:cohort]} cohort"
  end
end
```

Why doesn't the #While loop work with similar input, and why is it trying to convert to an integer?

Comment: Which line is 24th?

Comment: puts "#{students[:name]}, #{students[:cohort]} cohort"

In print(students) method.

Comment: `while !name.empty?` → `until name.empty?`. Or use a `loop` and `break if name.empty?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `#each` loop was shadowing the `students` variable:

```
# v                              v
students.each.with_index(1) do |students, index|
  puts "#{index} #{students[:name]}, #{students[:cohort]} cohort"
end
```

you iterate an array called `students` and then assign each element in the array to a variable named `students`. When you get rid of the `each` loop, you didn't change the block to stop looking at `students`, so it's now looking at the array. To get a single element try:

```
def print(students)
  i = 0
  while i < students.length
    puts "#{students[i][:name]}, #{students[i][:cohort]} cohort"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  while i < students.length
    puts "#{students[:name]}, #{students[:cohort]} cohort"
  end
```

`students` is an array. You can't address its elements with symbols. What you need to do is use `i` to fetch an *element* of students. You can call `[:name]` on that.

The mistake comes, I think, from poor naming in this snippet. And/or not understanding how `each` works.

```
students.each.with_index(1) do |students, index|  
#                                ^^^^^^
#  This here is called `students`, but its value is a single student, 
#  not a collection of students.
```

Comment: Is this different with #Each? The most confusing part is that it works with an #Each loop.

Comment: Just like it's written in another answer - you were shadowing `students` variable inside of block passed to `each`.